# how to set position of center image with responsive in css?

Tags: angularjs, html, css

Please look at my html:

```
                    <div class="row">
                <div  class="row-fluid ">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 SetPadding">
                        <a href="#" id="button1" "></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 SetPadding">
                        <a href="#" id="button2" ></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div  class="row-fluid ">

                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 SetPadding textaligncenter">
                        <a href="#" id="centerbutton" ></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div  class="row-fluid ">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 SetPadding">
                         <a href="#" id="button3" ></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 SetPadding">
                         <a href="#" id="button4" ></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
#button1 {background: url('../img/button1.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;display: inline-block;width:100%;padding-bottom:45%;}
                #button2 {background: url('../img/button2.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;display: inline-block;width:100%;padding-bottom:45%;}
                **#centerbutton{background: url('../img/buttoncenter.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;display: inline-block;width:100%;padding-bottom:45%;}**
                #button3 {background: url('../img/button3.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;display: inline-block;width:100%;padding-bottom:45%;}
                #button4 {background: url('../img/button4.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;display: inline-block;width:100%;padding-bottom:45%;}
```

My expected out put is

[image]

i have already tried absolute positions of center button, but that creating problem while resizing window

Comment: please upload your images

Comment: Are those `.row-`/`.col-` classes from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)? Maybe add this as a tag (and remove the AngularJS tag which is not related to this problem at all)?

Comment: it will be best if you can set a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You HTML element is called id="centerbutton"

but your CSS is targeting #buttoncenter

.....or at least it was until you edited it